# Create a hardlink from the network

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hardlink

I'm trying to create an NTFS hardlink over a network drive:

- I'm using Windows an XP SP3 workstation
- mapped drive F: over a Windows 7 Server with

  > net use f: \\server\shared_folder
- then I try

  > fsutil hardlink create new_entry existing_file

That works locally on the server, but not when I try to do it over the network using the mapped drive (F:). The error shown is:

> The FSUTIL utility needs a local NTFS drive

(or somewhat like that, my error message is in Spanish)

Is there any way to create the hardlink from the network share or should I access the physical server remotely every time I need to create a hardlink?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot create a hardlink to a remote drive, or even between two local drives. A hardlink must point from one point in a filesystem to another point *in that exact same filesystem*.

What you want is a symbolic link, which acts more like a shortcut, and can point to remote files or shares.

Comment: yes, I'm aware that hardlinks only works over the same filesystem, but I wanted to create that hardlink over the same *network* filesystem. Symbolics links doesn't work for me, because the application program that uses the files apparently checks the directory entry of each linked file and reports them as "corrupt".

Comment: @PabloG Ah, then no, you must simply create them remotely. Windows shares use a protocol called CIFS, which doesn't expose the ability to create hardlinks. Creating hardlinks requires knowing intimate data about the destination filesystem, and that could create security issues.

Comment: ok then, I'm going to use PsExec from SysInternals to run the fsutil command from any machine from the network, thx

Comment: Technically I think SMB is a superset of CIFS, but neither supports creating hardlinks AFAIK.

Comment: @HarryJohnston [`SMB`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) is the same thing as `CIFS`

Comment: That article is wrong, although my previous comment wasn't quite right either.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/a/397791/94065 and http://serverfault.com/a/370275/94065 for examples that the distinction between SMB and CIFS is not entirely theoretical.

Answer (score 4):

I use this command to create symbolic links on windows (almost aways in my web server folders of xampp).
This is an example to use that:

```
mklink /D "C:\mySMBremoteServer" "\\server\shared_folder"
```

- mklink -> command to create links
- /D -> create a simbolic link (manage the same folder remotely)
- "Locale_folder" -> path to make the local link
- "remote_link" -> path to the samba server

I leave here the manual [mklink Windows manual](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and I hope it helps.

**SPANISH TRASLATION**

Yo uso este comando para mi servidor local de xampp ya que no hay manera de crear carpetas virtuales... si no te funciona (a mi hasta la fecha me va de lujo) prueba con la opcion /H aun que no la he probado.

Este comando lo que hace es crear un "acceso directo" al destino que quieras, modificandolo si así es necesario remotamente